# How to change the location of .pdb files for static libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Now I found out I can change the `.pdb` file location for C++ executable projects in `Linking` -> `Debugger` in the project settings.

How can I change the location for static library projects? As they do not have the `Linker` menu.

I tried changing `C/C++` -> `Output files` -> `Program Database File Name`, but without luck. They are still added to the same directory as the compiled executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the `Program Database File Name`,  `pdb` will be added to the specified directory. In addition, if the lib file directories are not changed,  another `pdb` file will also be added aside the lib. This may be why you think it was unsuccessful, but in fact it has been done.

Comment: Why will the other package be added?

Comment: I didn't find the relevant documentation. Maybe `the debugger only loads .pdb files that exactly match the .pdb files created when an app was built (that is, the original .pdb files or copies)`? Link [How symbol files work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019#how-symbol-files-work). I recommend going to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=62) and asking Microsoft's developers.